# How to create a document Cloud in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, cloud, webdav

I am trying to create a document cloud in ASP.NET C#.

My users get their documents scanned and uploaded to my webpage where we OCR it and covnert it to a DOC..

The DOCS are displayed in a Gridview which they can click on to download.. I want them to be able to click the document and for it to open in Word and then in Word they should be able to just click SAVE and it saves back to the webpage..
I notice Hotmail does this on their SkyDrive (only works in IE, not FireFox). Also Sharepoint does this.

I think they both use WebDav but I am wont have to change my whole progam to include WebDav so that I can support this..

I have run a little test where I allowed full read/write access to a webpage and I downloaded the document (ie http://www.myserver.com/test.doc) Word would open it but would open it as Read-Only, so they could not clikc Save.. However if they clicked Save-As they could still save it back to the HTTP..

Is it possible to do? Also Can it be done in FireFox/chrome?

Comment: Have you got any solution ? have you tried with WebDAV ? http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer has an integrated ActiveX control that allows it to marshal the call to the associated application. Documents are associated with a particular application via the [DOCICON.XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463701.aspx) file. Firefox does not include this ActiveX control. That's why what you are going to achieve seems to me not possible.

**Update**: I've found [this](http://www.qa.downappz.com/questions/save-word-document-on-server-via-webdav-on-server-2008-and-iis-7-error-read-only.html).

> In authentication methods i needed to enable integrated Windows, and
>   Basic authentication for my virtual folder. (i only had Basic authentication 
>   enabled)
>
> Then the document wasn't read-only, and i could save on server.

Comment: Do I have to do something special for it to open the HTTP file in IE as not read-only so I can save it back?

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix, if it's an option for you, would be to keep the web interface but share out the location where the documents are stored on the network.  Then you could change the links in your gridview to point to the network share instead of the http address, ie `\\fileserver\ocrout\file.docx` instead of `http://myiisserver/ocrout/file.docx`.

Depending on your setup this may not work for you, but it does make life easier if you can.

If permissions are a concern have no fear.  Give your service account full control to the NTFS folders involved and you can manage permissions on the folders through your web interface by writing a little C# code.

Comment: unforuntely i want it to work over a WAN not just a LAN.. so this option wont really work

Answer (score 0):

Whacky thought, but could you have the client in wpf or silverlight, then when they select a file it downloads, saves into local storage opens word etc, monitors for changes and queues the file back for upload? I suppose this would tie you to IE. or similar approach  with some other local helper app or service?